Oracle function to Snowflake function conversion
I am trying to convert the below Oracle function to Snowflake function. I needed some help in this as I am not that familiar with Snowflake.
I have tried some functions to convert the below code to make it compatible to Snowflake but I am facing hurdles.
This is the Oracle code:
CREATE OR REPLACE function schema_1.getCName(CCodes VARCHAR2)
  return varchar2
as
  TYPE results_type IS REF CURSOR;
  results results_type;
  CValue VARCHAR2(1023 CHAR);
  CCodesForInClause VARCHAR2(511 CHAR) DEFAULT '';
  CCodesValue VARCHAR2(510 CHAR);
  cursorQuery VARCHAR2(1023 CHAR) DEFAULT '';
  CNames VARCHAR2(1023 CHAR);
begin
  CNames := '';
  IF(instr(CCodes,',') > 0) THEN
    CCodesValue := CCodes;
    WHILE (instr(CCodesValue,',') > 0)
    LOOP
      CCodesForInClause := CCodesForInClause || '''' || 
        trim(substr(CCodesValue, 0, instr(CCodesValue,',')-1)) || 
        ''',';
      CCodesValue := substr(CCodesValue, instr(CCodesValue,',') + 1, 
        LENGTH(CCodesValue) - instr(CCodesValue,','));
    END LOOP;

    CCodesForInClause := CCodesForInClause || '''' || trim(CCodesValue) || '''';
    cursorQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME FROM Table1 WHERE C_ABBREV IN ' || '(' ||  CCodesForInClause || ') order by C_NAME';

    OPEN results FOR cursorQuery;
    LOOP
      IF (length(trim(CValue)) > 0) THEN
        CNames := CNames || CValue || ';';
      END IF;
      FETCH results INTO CValue;
      EXIT WHEN results%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    IF (length(trim(CNames)) > 0) THEN
      CNames := substr(CNames, 1, length(CNames)-1);
    END IF;
    CLOSE results;
  ELSE
    OPEN results FOR 'SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME FROM Table1 WHERE C_ABBREV = :cc' USING CCodes;
    FETCH results into CValue;

      IF (results%FOUND) THEN
        CNames := CValue;
      END IF;
      CLOSE results;
    END IF;

    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(CNames);
    return CNames;
end;

This is the Snowflake code I have tried: I am getting error while trying to call the PROCEDURE:

Error: invalid identifier 'RESULT_SET' (line 72)

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema1.CName(cCodes STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    CValue STRING;
    cCodesForInClause STRING DEFAULT '';
    cCodesValue STRING;
    cursorQuery STRING;
    cNames STRING DEFAULT '';
    result_set resultset  ;
BEGIN
   IF(regexp_instr(cCodes,',') > 0) THEN
        cCodesValue := cCodes;

    WHILE (instr(cCodesValue,',') > 0)
    LOOP
      cCodesForInClause := cCodesForInClause || '''' || trim(substr(cCodesValue, 0, regexp_instr(cCodesValue,',')-1)) || ''',';
      cCodesValue := substr(cCodesValue, instr(cCodesValue,',') + 1, LENGTH(cCodesValue) - instr(cCodesValue,','));
    END LOOP;

    cCodesForInClause := cCodesForInClause || '''' || trim(cCodesValue) || '''';
    cursorQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME FROM Table1 WHERE C_ABBREV IN ' || '(' ||  cCodesForInClause || ') order by C_NAME'
    ;
OPEN result_set FOR cursorQuery;
LOOP
    IF (length(trim(CValue)) > 0) THEN
       cNames := cNames || CValue || ';';
      END IF;
    FETCH result_set INTO CValue;
    --EXIT WHEN results%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;  
IF (length(trim(cNames)) > 0) THEN
      cNames := substr(cNames, 1, length(cNames)-1);
    END IF;
    ELSE
    cursorQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME FROM ONESRC_DEV.ONESRC_OWNER.EmergingMarketsRegions where WHERE C_ABBREV = :cc';
    result_set := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :cursorQuery);
        -- Fetch the result
        IF (RESULTSET_HAS_ROWS(result_set)) THEN
            FETCH result_set INTO CValue;
            IF (LENGTH(TRIM(CValue)) > 0) THEN
                cNames := CValue;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        END IF;
        return cNames;
        END;$$;

        call Schema1.CName('USA');


Hi. - you haven’t actually asked a question. You need to show the code that you have managed to write. You haven’t explained what the “hurdles” are that you are facing: are you getting errors (what are they), is it giving incorrect results (what are they and what should they be), etc?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i am posting the query(the one which i had tried from my end) in the answer, could you please help me. @NickW

@JeetChatterjee - that code is not an answer; you should edit your question to include it there. I've moved it for you this time (so you can delete your answer), but please make further edits to add the other information NickW asked for.

Hi @AlexPoole, i have provided the error as well in the question which i am getting while calling the function.

Hi - I'd start by reading up on how to use RESULTSETs and CURSORs in Snowflake SQL scripting (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets). For example, assigning a string to the cursorQuery variable and then running "OPEN result_set FOR cursorQuery;" is not going to do anything

Still I am unable to convert the code to snowflake compatible code. (I am not very comfortable with Snowflake) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

OK - for a start you need to define your cursor in the DECLARE section: cursorQuery CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT C_NAME FROM Table1 WHERE C_ABBREV IN ' || '(' ||  cCodesForInClause || ') order by C_NAME'; In the main block of code you need to open the cursor: OPEN cursorQuery; You can then loop through the records in the cursor using a FOR loop. All this is documented with examples here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors

Hi @NickW, this is the fucntion i came up with, but getting error
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCtryName(countryCodes VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
COALESCE(
(SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT COUNTRY_NAME, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COUNTRY_NAME)
FROM EmergingMarketsRegions
WHERE COUNTRY_ABBREV IN
(SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(countryCodes, ',')))
),  '')
$$;

its only working when i am passing direct values into it (ex 'USA,MEX,CAN'). I am getting the expected output ('UNITEDSTATESOFAMERICA;MEXICO;CANADA'). But when i am passing a column name into the function which contain the country codes(ex USA,MEX,CAN), then i am getting an error 'Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated'. Could you please help. Expectation : select getcname(column_name) from table2; Output: 'UNITEDSTATESOFAMERICA;MEXICO;CANADA'

Please edit your question to show the latest version of your function. As a general point, it makes it difficult for people to understand the current state of a question if information is spread across comments (plus, as you can’t format comments, putting code/data in comments makes it difficult to read)
